# How to resize image from text box value at runtime in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here i have two textbox name LabelHeight and LabelWidth and a image.I load the image from the default value given to the labelheight and labelwidth. now i want to change the image height an width when i change those textbox value in runtime. I am  a newb in WPF.
This is my MainViewModel Class Where i declare two properties with value

```
 public int LabelWidth { get; set; } = 305;
    public int LabelHeight { get; set; } = 200;
```

this is my xml

```
<Image x:Name="Image" 
           Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
               Source="Images/Norsel.bmp" 
               Height="{Binding LabelHeight}"  
               Width="{Binding LabelWidth}"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding LabelWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding LabelHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: @Stefan Yea Edited my Code. I'm using mvvm. Any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the height and width.

Assuming that `INotifyProperChanged` has been set up correctly on your viewmodel, something like this for the width

```
private int _labelWidth = 305;
public int LabelWidth 
{ 
     get { return _labelWidth; }  
     set 
     { 
         _labelWidth = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("LabelWidth");
     }
}
```

Comment: then what would be the xaml for notifyproperty Change. can you give me an example? I have Applied this but can you give a example for the text box and image.

Comment: Just having the binding mode two way on the image height and width should fix your issue with this

Comment: It Changes it size but i Think It Depends on each other height and width. Like if i give a value in height and make the width 0 then it doesn't show any image after giving a width value than it changes.

Comment: Make sure the height and width has a min value from stopping that happen, you can do that many ways, all are pretty trivial

Comment: If this answered your question, maybe accept it. No worries, have fun.